# Category active product count on category list

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category, php-5.4

I am trying to display number of products in in each category.. 
and using this code to display all subcategory of category id:3
It is showing but it is counting not visible and disable product also,

```
<?php
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($cats as $category): ?>
    <li>
         <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?>(<?php echo $category->getProductCount(); ?>)</a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Is there any good solution so that i can get exact count thats are visible-catalog search and active.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Follow that one:

```
$collection=$category->getProductCollection();
$collection->setVisibility(array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG));     
$collection->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
echo $collection->count();
```

Comment: yes, using collection is the right way to fix your problem.